# C# dll can be used in C++/CLI project easily?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have one C++/CLI project, a GUI application, which is compiled in mixed mode (managed+unmanaged).
Now I want to write a custom user control using C# and compile it to become CSharpA.dll.
my question is:  Can this dll be used by my C++/CLI project easily?  How would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Just add a reference to it.  You may find yourself wanting `using namespace` directives, which, like the C# `using` directive, will add classes in other namespaces into the search space.

Comment: if i add the C# ctrl dll into my Cli/c++ project ,another question is can i see ctrl in the ToolBox page , can i drag the C# ctrl into my cli/C++ form visibly?

Comment: As long as the control is public, you should find it in the toolbox.  IIRC, Visual Studio automatically creates a new group in the toolbox for controls in the current project, but for referenced control libraries you might have to right-click the toolbox and add the library content.

Comment: acturally, i ever created one user control in Cli/C++ but didn't see this item in toolbox..

Comment: if i do this in C# that's OK just like what you described.

Comment: @Biwier: I'm getting lost trying to understand what you are getting to work and what doesn't.  Please be clear about: What language the control library is written in, whether you are trying to find the control in the toolbox when building a form in the same project, different project same language, or different project different language.  And then whether it's showing up for you the way you want.

Comment: here is what i did in my Cli/C++ program:  I created A project, and in the A project, i created a Form named bform  and a user control named cComtermizedCtrl , and i compiled the project successfully ,but I coundn't find the cComtermizedCtrl  control in toolbox. why?   i did the same thing in C# , I could find a new control was added into toolbox automatically  after compiling.

Comment: question 2: how can i add the cComtermizedCtrl into toolbox so that I can drag the control into bform visibly?

Answer (score 0):

You only have to compile your C# code into an assembly, and this assembly can be referenced from your C++/CLI App as any other assembly.